# Object change places in render view

Tags: modeling, rendering, 3d-view, lighting, displacement

I have an object that I di some sculpting on. After baking a displacement map, I wanted to try it out and see if it works. As the scene was dark, I decided to add a light, and things got worse in a way that I didn't expect. I'm not really sure what's going on, but when I change the view mode from material view to render view, my object changes its location. Does anyone have an idea what is going on and how can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume it's cycles render engine ? Could you add the node tree of the material you used ? Specifically how you plugged the displacement map into the output node

Comment: Yes, it is in Cycles. I edited with a screenshot of the node tree.

Comment: You need to plug the texture into the height, not the normal input of the displacement node. Also you can play with the scale if it seems too high

Comment: Thank you. The normal and the scale were indeed a problem.

Comment: @susu I would but I'm pretty sure this is a multi-duplicate which I saw one other like yesterday, but I can't find it... but oh well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to plug the texture color into the *height*, and not the *normal* input of the displacement node.

You can play with the *scale* field if the displacement seems too high.